# Is it possible to avoid duplication of code in this case

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have got five input fields

```
<input data-category="0" class="ncr_input" type="text" name="name" maxlength="25" id="t1cat" value=""   placeholder="T1" autocomplete="off"/>
<input data-category="1" class="ncr_input" type="text" maxlength="25"  name="name" id="t2cat" value=""  placeholder="T2" autocomplete="off" />
 <input data-category="2" class="ncr_input" type="text" maxlength="25"  name="name" id="t3cat" value=""  placeholder="T4" autocomplete="off" />
 <input data-category="3" class="ncr_input" type="text" maxlength="25"  name="name" id="t4cat" value=""  placeholder="T4" autocomplete="off" />
 <input data-category="4" class="ncr_input" type="text" maxlength="25"  name="name" id="t5cat" value=""  placeholder="T4" autocomplete="off" />
```

I have to restrict certain common  characters under these five text fields .

The in line style onkeyPress is not working in mobile (But working fine on desktop browser)

So i made it this way

```
$(function() {

$('#t1cat').keypress(function(evt) {

    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

            if (charCode ==37 || charCode ==38  ) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
});


$('#t2cat').keypress(function(evt) {

     evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;

            if (charCode ==37 || charCode ==38  ) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
});


similar code for t3cat t4cat and t5cat also 




});
```

This is working fine , but my question is , is it possible to avoid duplication of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery selectors in different ways.

One way is a comma delimited list of the ids:

```
$('#t1cat,#t2cat,#t2cat,#t3cat,#t5cat').on("keypress", function(evt) {
     evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode ==37 || charCode ==38  ) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
});
```

Another way is to use a common class from the inputs and use that class as the selector. If only these inputs have the selector, ncr_input:

```
$('.ncr_input').on("keypress", function(evt) {
     evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
            var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            if (charCode ==37 || charCode ==38  ) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
});
```

If that class is used elsewhere, simply assign a class name that is not used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript solution:

To avoid repetition, you may want to use [onkeypress Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) :

```
<input data-category="0" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(event);" class="ncr_input" type="text" name="name" maxlength="25" id="t1cat" value=""   placeholder="T1" autocomplete="off"/>
<input data-category="1" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(event);" class="ncr_input" type="text" maxlength="25"  name="name" id="t2cat" value=""  placeholder="T2" autocomplete="off" />
<input data-category="2" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(event);" class="ncr_input" type="text" maxlength="25"  name="name" id="t3cat" value=""  placeholder="T4" autocomplete="off" />
<input data-category="3" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(event);" class="ncr_input" type="text" maxlength="25"  name="name" id="t4cat" value=""  placeholder="T4" autocomplete="off" />
<input data-category="4" onkeypress="return restrictCharacters(event);" class="ncr_input" type="text" maxlength="25"  name="name" id="t5cat" value=""  placeholder="T4" autocomplete="off" />


function restrictCharacters(e) {
  if (!e) var e = window.event
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
     else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    // if they pressed % or &... remove focus from field...
       if (code==37 || code==38) { this.blur(); return false; }

}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/pJoMvp)